# 13.15 python-bot-client callback for uploading recorded audio

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I use version 13.15 of PTB. My purpose is to make simple bot that upload audio recorded by user at Telegram client.

This is the *main*

```
def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Register handlers
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.audio, handle_audio))
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
```

Callback function `handle_audio` *is* called when in Telegram client I choose stored audio file and upload it in bot dialog.
However, if in the same dialog I press microphone icon, record audio and send it,  `handle_audio` is not called.
What is wrong?

Comment: please note that ptbs dev team no longer supports v13.x. I recommend to upgrade to v20.x

Comment: @CallMeStag, in this case, as long as I do no use venv,  I limited to Python packages supported by last OS of  Raspberry Pi.

Comment: AFAIK the latest raspian includes python3.9. PTB 20.7 supports python 3.8-3.12, which would suffice.

Comment: @CallMeStag, 
Last Raspian OS (Bookworm) manage Python packages via apt. They have configured list of supported packages, which include PTB 13.15-1, bit not PTB 20

See http://rptl.io/venv

Comment: I see. Still, this reference does explain that you can use pip as long as you use virtual environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.voice, handle_audio))
```

rather then

```
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.audio, handle_audio))
```